# How do I delete the element that I clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with input fields whose values are to be stored in an array in the form of an object. At the same time, these values are displayed in the browser. Now I want to allow the user to delete the displayed values, i.e. the created object. Unfortunately, the function I have set up so far "deletes" very randomly (that's how it seems to me). What do I have to change so that the function deletes the element that is clicked?

HTML:

```html
<div class="readContainer">
    <label for="radio">read?</label>
    <div class="checkReadContainer">
        <input type="checkbox" id="read" name="read" value="yes">
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btn" onclick="createBook();">submit</button>
</div>

<div class="displayMessageContainer">
    <p id="displayBook"> store up to 10 books </p>
    <p id="infoTestVersion"> or <a href="#" id="signUp"> sign up </a>for our free trial and get 30 days of unlimited
        storage for your books*</p>
</div>

<div class="Display">
    <p class="display"> </p>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="footerContainer">
        <div class="madeBy">
            <h1> made by anitakath <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i> </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

JavaScript:

```js
const labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const title = document.getElementById("title");
const author = document.getElementById("author");
const pages = document.getElementById("pages");
const button = document.getElementById("btn");
const displayArea = document.querySelector(".display");

let myLibrary = [];

function Book(title, author, pages) {
  this.title = title.value;
  this.author = author.value;
  this.pages = pages.value;
}

Book.prototype.introduction = function () {
  return `${this.title} by ${this.author}, `;
};

Book.prototype.introductionII = function () {
  return `with ${this.pages} pages`;
};

let errorMessage = document.getElementById("displayBook");

function createBook() {
  if (title.value && author.value && pages.value) {

    let bookX = new Book(title, author, pages);
 
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("cardStyle");
    displayArea.appendChild(card);

    let cardSectionLeft = document.createElement("div");
    let cardSectionRight = document.createElement("div");
    cardSectionLeft.classList.add("cardLeft");
    cardSectionRight.classList.add("cardRight");

    card.appendChild(cardSectionLeft);
    card.appendChild(cardSectionRight);

    let deleteButton = document.createElement("div");
    let deleteContent = document.createElement("p");
    deleteContent.innerText = "X";
    deleteButton.classList.add("deleteButton");
    deleteButton.appendChild(deleteContent);
    cardSectionRight.appendChild(deleteButton);

    deleteButton.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteBook();");

    let cardIntro = document.createElement("h3");
    let cardOutro = document.createElement("p");
    cardIntro.innerText = bookX.introduction();
    cardOutro.innerText = bookX.introductionII();
    cardSectionLeft.appendChild(cardIntro);
    cardSectionRight.appendChild(cardOutro);

    bookArray = [title.value, author.value, pages.value];

    const bookArrayToObject = Object.assign({}, bookArray);
    console.log(bookArrayToObject);

    myLibrary.push(bookArrayToObject);
    console.log(myLibrary);
    console.log(myLibrary[0]);
    console.log(myLibrary[1]);
    console.log(myLibrary[2]);

    const radio = document.getElementById("read");
    if (radio.checked) {
      card.classList.add("read");
    } else if (!radio.checked) {
      card.classList.add("notread");
    }

    errorMessage.innerText = `saved: ${this.title.value} by ${this.author.value}, with ${this.pages.value} pages`;
    errorMessage.style.color = "green";
  } else if (!title.value || !author.value || !pages.value) {
    errorMessage.innerText =
      "please make sure you have filled in all input fields";
    errorMessage.style.color = "red";
  }
}

function deleteBook() {
  for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
    console.log(myLibrary.splice(i, 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach listeners. Then the handler will receive `event` object, it contains `target` property, which is a reference to the element triggered the event. Then use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the "card", and then [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) it. Consider to use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for storing data.

Answer (score 1):

The `splice` method on JavaScript arrays mutates the array *in place*. This means that, once it's run (even if you're just logging the result, etc), it's already actually changed the array.

Let's take a closer look at what it does, from the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.
>
> - `start`: Zero-based index at which to start changing the array
> - `deleteCount`: An integer indicating the number of elements in the array to remove from start.
> - Returns: **An array containing the deleted elements.**

I believe you're probably expecting that return value to be the new array, with just the element you want deleted, and that's why the result looks like it's deleting a "random" element as you put it.

---

So, lets look at how to delete correctly, either you can take in the index of the book, or you can take in the book itself and delete it (I think that's the better approach, but you'll have to do a little refactoring to get there).

```
function deleteBookByIndex(bookIndex) {
  myLibrary.splice(bookIndex, 1);
}

function deleteBook(book) {
  const bookIndex = myLibrary.indexOf(book);
  myLibrary.splice(bookIndex, 1);
}
```

You will, of course, also need to think about how updates to your internal data store are reflected in the HTML, e.g. to remove the element. Ideally maybe your `Book` class keeps some reference to the DOM elements that you create, so you can directly update them, as that would be cleaner than having to go searching through the DOM to find them again later.

---

A few notes on your code as it stands:

- ```
  deleteButton.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteBook();")
  ```

  Using the `onclick` etc attributes on HTML is very much not the recommended way to add event listeners anymore, as it only allows for one, and you have to write JavaScript code as a string, which is problematic for many reasons --- especially in a case like this one, where we'll want to pass an argument in. Instead, lets do it like so:

  ```
  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", () => deleteBook());
  ```
- You seem to create both an class instance (`let bookX = new Book(title, author, pages);`), an array (`bookArray = [title.value, author.value, pages.value]`) and an object (`Object.assign({}, bookArray)`) to represent your book. My advice would be to pick one representation and stick with it.
- Use ES6 classes rather than the prototype approach you have here at the moment if you choose to stick with using the `Book` class.

Comment: Toastrackenigma thank you a lot!! :-) this really helped me!